How can I open a new Safari window with bash?
I'm working on a project that will let me open and close different pre-saved combinations of urls in different browsing windows. Since osascript/osascript/AppleScript or whatever they're calling it now is on borrowed time, I wanted to do this with bash or something with more longevity.
But I'm having trouble figuring out how to just open a new window in Safari. What I want to do is for the script to open a new Safari window with the URL as the first tab address. Is this not possible with bash? I've tried a couple things and none of them have worked:
Everything I've found so far says you can open a Safari window with open -a Safari but all this does for me is switch to an already open Safari window.
When I add a URL param like open -a Safari https://www.google.com, it switches to a current open Safari window and opens a new tab with the URL.
When I use the -n flag like open -n -a Safari https://www.google.com, it refreshes all the already open Safari window tabs and opens a new tab with the URL. Confused why this this doesn't work since this is the man description:
-n, --new             Open a new instance of the application even if one is already running.

Hoping someone can help me figure this out. Is this just isn't possible with bash? or even if it is, should it actually just be done with osascript despite the fact it's no longer supported? Appreciate any help/thoughts/redirection to other more suitable frameworks to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

open -n -a  Safari  worked for me. I tried it 3 times with open -n -a Safari https://www.google.com in zsh and bash. Each time I got a new instance of Safari.

If you simply use the open command, Safari will open your URL in a new tab or new window, depending on the end user's preferences. You can test different experiences in Safari by opening Settings > Tabs and playing with the options for opening pages in tabs instead of windows.
AppleScript and osascript are your only options to control whether Safari opens URLs in new tabs or new windows, and Apple still very much supports them. (I wouldn't put much stock in someone's speculation that AppleScript is going away without solid supporting evidence, which can only come from Apple.) This isn't something you can do with bash alone.
This will open a new tab in the front window of Safari with your URL or open a new Safari window if one doesn't exist:
#!/bin/zsh

/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell application "Safari" to get front document'

if [[ "$?" -eq 0 ]]; then
    # open URL in new tab of a Safari window if one exists
    /usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell application "Safari" to make new tab with properties {URL: "https://www.apple.com"} at front window'
else
    # open URL in new Safari window
    /usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell application "Safari" to make new document with properties {URL: "https://www.apple.com"}'
fi

You can use the second osascript command by itself to always open your URL in a new Safari window.
You don't want to use open -n because that literally opens a new Safari application rather than using the one that's currently running. When you do this, you'll notice two instances of Safari running in your dock or app switcher.

The simplest solution would be to change Safari's settings for tabs to open pages in windows. See the below image taken from Ventura 13.3.1 (a).

However, since you asked for bash, I will offer the following script, which does not use the osascript command. When necessary, this script temporarily changes the setting circled in red, so a new window is created instead of a new tab.

Note: In order for the defaults command to work properly when used in a Terminal window, the Terminal application will need to be given Full Disk Access. See Privacy & Security in the System Setting application (formally known as the System Preferences application).

#!/bin/bash
unset -v TabCreationPolicy ExitStatus
if ! TabCreationPolicy="$(defaults read -app Safari TabCreationPolicy 2>/dev/null)"; then
  TabCreationPolicy=1
fi
if [[ $TabCreationPolicy != 0 ]]; then
  defaults write -app Safari TabCreationPolicy 0
fi
open -a Safari "${1:-https://www.google.com}"
ExitStatus=$?
if [[ $TabCreationPolicy != 0 ]]; then
  defaults write -app Safari TabCreationPolicy "$TabCreationPolicy"
fi
exit $ExitStatus

The relationship between the selections available for the combo box shown in the above image and the value of the TabCreationPolicy key is given in the table below.



Open pages in tabs instead of windows
Value of TabCreationPolicy key




Never
0


Automatically
1 or nonexistent


Always
2



